# Yii: validation rules that always apply except one scenario

Tags: php, validation, yii, model, yii-validation

I know that you can have a validation rule that applies only for one scenario:

```
array('username', 'exist', 'on' => 'update'),
```

Now i would like to know if it's possible to do the opposite: a rule that applies everytime except for a given scenrio?

The only solution that is see right now is list all the others scenario, but it's not pretty if we need to add some news scenarios later.

```
array('username', 'exist', 'on' => array('create', 'search', ...),//all the scenarios except update
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of Yii 1.1.11 you can use `except` keyword:

```
array('username', 'exist', 'except' => 'update'),
```

Take a look at [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules). There is a little example there.

[Doc link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#except-detail)

Comment: Really good, I should have found it by myself since it's in the documentation (but not in the wikis about validation rules)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Work the same way in Yii 2.0.

```
['username', 'required', 'except' => 'update']
```

Every key in the array before the name of the validator is a property for the Validator Class itself. You can see the available properties in https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator

I know is an old question but every time I forgot that yii2 have an except property in the validator class.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation for more advanced technics